# How to get event name and value when using SunEditor and React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, react-hooks

I have dynamic inputs where I can add as many inputs in my form as I need, on the fly.

Here is my onChange and I think this is where the issue is.

```
const [formFields, setFormFields] = useState( dbObject || [{section: ''}])

const handleFormChange = (event, index) => {
    let data = [...formFields];
     //somewhere here
  data[index][event.target.name] = event.target.value;
    setFormFields(data);
}
```

I add an input like this

```
const addFields = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let object = {
        section: '',
    }
    setFormFields([...formFields, object])
}
```

The below code **works fine** with a default input. I get the expected behavior because I have the `'name'` on the input.

```
   {formFields.map((form, index) => {
                    return (
                   <div key={index}>
                       <TextField
                             id="outlined-multiline-flexible"
                             name='section'
                             value={form.section}
                             onChange={event => handleFormChange(event, index)}
                      />
                 </div>
                  ))}
```

**Problem**

The issue comes when I want to replace the default text input with a rich text editor. I am using [sunEditor][1] But the onChange wont work.

So in the map function, I am importing my sunEditor from a different file and doing the exact same thing.

```
<SunEditor onChange={(event: any) => handleFormChange(event, index)} contents={form.section}  />
```

But I get this error

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')
```

This brings me back to this code above

```
const handleFormChange = (event, index) => {
        let data = [...formFields];
         //somewhere here
      data[index][event.target.name] = event.target.value;
        setFormFields(data);
    }
```

How do I get my Sun Editor to work like the input? I've tried

```
const handleFormChange = (event, index) => {
            let data = [...formFields];
             //somewhere here
          data[index][content] = content;
            setFormFields(data);
        }
```

Because Suneditor has 'content'. And some other input manipulations, but I cant get it to work.
[1]: https://www.npmjs.com/package/suneditor-react

Answer (score 0):

the onChange function in the suneditor gives you the stringified contents of the whole suneditor rather than an event like a regular input.

```
export default function InputField({name, formFields}){ 
      const [value, setValue] = React.useState('')
      // Form Fields would be and object of all fields
      // formFields = {
      //    name: ''
      //   password: ''
      // }

      const onChange = (contents, core) => { 
      //   where contents is the content of the suneditor
      //   and core is the context of that suneditor
      // if you had entered a h1 header with Hello Word
      console.log(content)
      // the content would be:
      // "<h1>Hello World</h1>"
      // You could strip the tags with some jquery
      console.log($(content).text())
      // "Hello World"
      formFields[name] = $(content).text();
      setValue(content)
      }
   return (
    <Editor setContents={value} onChange={onChange} />       )
}
```

You could then call this InputField on a form and pass in a name prop with the whole forms field values